# Can't Install Apache2 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, apt, apache2, mysql, php

Hi I am unable to install Apache2 on Ubuntu 16.04. I need to run PHPUnit on Ubuntu but I am not able to install PHP since Apache is not installing on my PC. Then I tried to install mysql-server but that also I couldn't install so then I tried to install docker also so that I can make a container and use that but then docker is also not installing. I am also unable to completely remove them.

Any help would be beneficial. Thanks in Advance

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
apache2-data apache2-utils
Suggested packages:
apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine | apache2-suexec-custom
The following packages will be REMOVED:
docker-ce mysql-server-5.7
The following NEW packages will be installed:
apache2 apache2-data apache2-utils
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 2 to remove and 249 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/330 kB of archives.
After this operation, 136 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 205320 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing docker-ce (17.03.0~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/docker-ce.postrm: 18: /var/lib/dpkg/info/docker-                ce.postrm: deb-systemd-helper: not found
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--remove):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Removing mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postrm: /usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper:      /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--remove):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 126
Errors were encountered while processing:
docker-ce
mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Edit after fixes mentioned for removal of Packages :

I was able to remove these 2 packages but even after that on apt-get upgrade I am getting this

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libpango1.0-0 libpangox-1.0-0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
gnome-software gnome-software-common ubuntu-software
The following packages will be upgraded:
accountsservice adium-theme-ubuntu adwaita-icon-theme apparmor appmenu-qt5
apport apport-gtk appstream apt apt-utils apturl apturl-common bamfdaemon
bash-completion command-not-found command-not-found-data compiz compiz-core
compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default cups-browsed cups-filters
cups-filters-core-drivers deja-dup desktop-file-utils dh-python
distro-info-data dmidecode dpkg-dev firefox firefox-locale-en fonts-noto-cjk
fuse fwupd gdb gdbserver gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4
gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0
gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gir1.2-unity-5.0 glib-networking
glib-networking-common glib-networking-services gnome-calculator
gnome-calendar gnome-font-viewer gnome-menus gnome-session-bin
gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gnome-sudoku
gnome-system-monitor grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common
gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-tools
gstreamer1.0-x gtk2-engines-murrine gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-bin gvfs-common
gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse gvfs-libs humanity-icon-theme im-config
indicator-application indicator-bluetooth isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common
krb5-locales language-pack-en language-pack-en-base language-pack-gnome-en
language-pack-gnome-en-base language-selector-common language-selector-gnome
less libaccountsservice0 libapparmor-perl libappindicator3-1
libappstream-glib8 libappstream3 libbamf3-2 libboost-date-time1.58.0
libboost-filesystem1.58.0 libboost-iostreams1.58.0 libboost-system1.58.0
libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dbg libc6-dev libcompizconfig0
libcupsfilters1 libdbusmenu-glib4 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libdbusmenu-gtk4
libdecoration0 libdfu1 libdpkg-perl libexiv2-14 libfcitx-config4
libfcitx-gclient0 libfcitx-utils0 libfdisk1 libfontembed1 libframe6
libfreetype6 libfuse2 libfwupd1 libgail-3-0 libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin
libglib2.0-data libgnome-menu-3-0 libgssapi-krb5-2
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0
libgstreamer1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgweather-3-6
libgweather-common libido3-0.1-0 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0
libldap-2.4-2 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 libmetacity-private3a
libnautilus-extension1a libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-glib4 libnm-util2 libnm0
libnux-4.0-0 libnux-4.0-common libp11-kit0 libpackagekit-glib2-16
libplymouth4 libpoppler-glib8 libpoppler58 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0
libpulsedsp libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5
libqt5printsupport5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5test5 libqt5widgets5
libqt5xml5 libsmartcols1 libunity-control-center1 libunity-core-6.0-9
libunity-protocol-private0 libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop
libunity-settings-daemon1 libunity9 libupower-glib3 libwhoopsie0
libxatracker2 libxml2 light-themes lightdm locales lsb-release lshw
metacity-common mtools mtr-tiny multiarch-support mythes-en-us nano nautilus
nautilus-data network-manager nux-tools os-prober overlay-scrollbar
overlay-scrollbar-gtk2 p11-kit p11-kit-modules plymouth plymouth-label
plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text poppler-utils
printer-driver-brlaser pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils python3-apport python3-brlapi
python3-commandnotfound python3-distupgrade python3-problem-report
python3-pyparsing python3-update-manager python3-urllib3 resolvconf
sbsigntool shared-mime-info sni-qt sudo suru-icon-theme thermald
ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-docs ubuntu-drivers-common ubuntu-mobile-icons
ubuntu-mono ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
ubuntu-session unattended-upgrades unity unity-control-center
unity-control-center-faces unity-lens-applications unity-schemas
unity-scopes-runner unity-services unity-settings-daemon update-manager
update-manager-core update-notifier update-notifier-common upower
uuid-runtime vino whoopsie xbrlapi xdg-utils xdiagnose xinit
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-intel
255 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 60.0 MB/207 MB of archives.
After this operation, 10.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libc6-dbg amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6 [3,676 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libc6-dev amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6 [2,081 kB]
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libc-dev-bin amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6 [68.5 kB]
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libc6 amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6 [2,591 kB]
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 locales all 2.23-0ubuntu6 [3,200 kB]
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libc-bin amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6 [632 kB]
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libfreetype6 amd64 2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2.1 [316 kB]
Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 multiarch-support amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6 [6,826 B]
Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 firefox amd64 52.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [46.8 MB]
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 firefox-locale-en amd64 52.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [651 kB]
Fetched 60.0 MB in 1min 39s (603 kB/s)                                         
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 205305 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dbg_2.23-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dbg:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu6) over (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev_2.23-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu6) over (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libc-dev-bin_2.23-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc-dev-bin (2.23-0ubuntu6) over (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.23-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu6) over (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
(Reading database ... 205305 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../locales_2.23-0ubuntu6_all.deb ...
Unpacking locales (2.23-0ubuntu6) over (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libc-bin_2.23-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu6) over (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu6) ...
(Reading database ... 205305 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/apt_1.2.19_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apt.prerm: 11: /var/lib/dpkg/info/apt.prerm: deb-systemd-invoke: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 11: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: deb-systemd-invoke: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/apt_1.2.19_amd64.deb (--unpack):
subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apt.postinst: 84: /var/lib/dpkg/info/apt.postinst: deb-systemd-helper: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apt.postinst: 87: /var/lib/dpkg/info/apt.postinst: deb-systemd-helper: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apt.postinst: 94: /var/lib/dpkg/info/apt.postinst: deb-systemd-helper: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apt.postinst: 100: /var/lib/dpkg/info/apt.postinst: deb-systemd-invoke: not found
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/apt_1.2.19_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help I have to install Apache and PHP on this machine

Unedited part of this question was marked duplicate [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895151/unable-to-install-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: I also tried to get a new apt_1.2.19_amd64.deb file and install it but that also didn't worked

Comment: I uesd "cd /var/lib/dpkg/info" and deleted the files related to those 2 packages mentioned in first stack trace, should I do that for this file also?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install Apache on Ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/895151/unable-to-install-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04)